# Unity 2019.3.6f1 doesn't support android sdk 26 and jdk 1.8.0.131

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Why unity need JDK 1.8.0 & SDK & NDK 19, But When i Install JDK 1.8.0 & sdk 26 with platform & build tools it doesn't support?

I add unity.exe to unity hub using locate..

Should i install unity from unity hub?
Also when i want to install it from hub there is no open jdk.
My hub version is 2.3

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.